# How can I set a border color when I set border-image in a QToolButton?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I am trying to create a QToolButton with a resized image, a background color and a border.  I have successfully gotten the image (using border-image) and background color to appear correctly.  However, I cannot seem to get the border to show as it appears the background color is "covering" it.

I am trying to do this using stylesheets in Qt Creator 2.7.0 with Qt 4.8.4.

My stylesheet is:

```
border-radius: 4px;
border: 2px solid red;
border-image: url(myImage) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
border-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: rgb(100, 255, 100);
```

I can create the look I want by using a QLabel, setting the pixmap to my image and then setting the border and background color in my stylesheet, but I need this to be a clickable button.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the solution was pretty simple, but I'll cover the two cases I tried first for completeness.

Setting background-image on a QToolButton places the image on the button at the original size of the image.  That is, it doesn't scale the image, nor does it resize when you resize the button.  Using background-image did allow me to set the border that I wanted, however, so this was what I thought I had to do at first.

Setting border-image on a QToolButton places the image on the button at a scaled size to fit the button and it rescales when you resize the button.  Unfortunately, this method overrides the border style I was trying to set.

Ultimately, the solution is to simply use image, not background-image or border-image.  This gives me everything I want: an image that scales with the button and the border style I wanted.

My stylesheet is now:

```
border-radius: 4px;
border: 2px solid red;
image: url(myImage) 2 2 2 2 stretch stretch;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: rgb(100, 255, 100);
```

Edit: The caveat to using just image is that it will scale down if necessary, but not up.  If your button is larger than your image, your image will not stretch to fit your button.  Fortunately for me my image was larger than my button, so it scaled down.  See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#image-prop

Comment: It also works for Qt 5. Thank you! (tested on: Ubuntu, Qt Creator 4.5.2, Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0, 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image using `background-image`, since you are using the `border-image` it overrides your style set to `border`

```
border-radius: 4px;
border: 2px solid red;
background-image: url(:/myImage.png);
background-color: rgb(100, 255, 100);
```

Comment: A background image isn't scalable on a QToolButton.  If the image is too large, it goes beyond the bounds of the button.  If it is too small the image is not stretched to the size of the button.  I think am using border-image appropriately, I just can't get the border to work.  I am copying an older version of the UI that has the button as a QToolButton but uses the palette to set everything, and it seems to work correctly for that, but I want to upgrade to using the stylesheets.